# Linkedin Profile URL

Tags: web, oauth, linkedin-api

I was using this url to view a linkedin profile using user id:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=USER_ID
```

But now the link is not working. tried it from some user and i keep getting this error from linked:

```
There was an unexpected problem that prevented us from completing your request.
```

used this code to get the linked in user ID:

```
F.Promise<WSResponse> linkedinInfoResponse = WS.url(Play.application().configuration().getString("api_call_url")) .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token) .setHeader("x-li-format", "json") .get();
```

Any idea whats the issue??

Comment: Can we see what code you are using to do this?

Comment: F.Promise<WSResponse> linkedinInfoResponse =
                 WS.url(Play.application().configuration().getString("api_call_url"))
                .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
                .setHeader("x-li-format", "json")
                .get(); and i get the id from the response and use it in the above url, it was working months ago but now link is not working!

Comment: Add it to the question, please, in a code block (edit the question, paste it in, select it, hit Control-K).  Make sure it is formatted nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1.) Clear the cache and cookies from your browser.

2.) Log out and login again.

3.) Log in from another browser.

Comment: tried it. not working! also tried different browser and different machine!